# Any array function available the values in php

Tags: php, arrays, kohana

This is my total array

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [food_name] => Chicken Briyani [food_id] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [food_name] => Sweet Corn Chicken Soup [food_id] => 6 ) )
```

I Need to delete the values from the array

```
[1] => Array ( [food_name] => Sweet Corn Chicken Soup [food_id] => 6 )
```

and need to get the `[0] => Array ( [food_name] => Chicken Briyani [food_id] => 4`

Answer (score 2):

Use `unset(your_array[1]);`

More: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: perfect. Any explanation would be more handy. +1

Comment: I have compare two tables one table have Food id - 1,2,3 and another table have 1,2 , I need to select 3 only. That is my question

Answer (score 1):

Besides deleting an array element by index, you could also delete an entry by `food_name` or `food_id` if you loop through the array and look for these values.

If you want to delete a specific entry, for example the `Chickem Briyani` one, you're going to have to loop through the array and also look for the array keys. Then, make a if statement on which entry you want to delete, based on the `food_name` or `food_id`.

```
$items = array(
  array('food_name' => 'Chickem Briyani', 'food_id' => 4),
  array('food_name' => 'Sweet Corn Chicken Soup', 'food_id' => 6)
);

foreach($items as $key => $item) {
  if($item['food_name'] == "Chickem Briyani") {
    unset($items[$key]);
  }
}
```

Now you can delete the specific array index, which belongs to that specific `food_name` or `food_id`.

To see the final output of the array, simply use

```
print_r($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove any unwanted values by id.

```js
$arr = array(
 array('food_name'=>'Chickem Briyani','food_id'=>4),
  array('food_name'=>'Sweet Corn Chicken Soup','food_id'=>6)
);

$newarr = array_filter($arr,function($innerArr){
  if($innerArr['food_id'] === 6){
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});
print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your requirement:**

You have a multi-dimensional array with keys `0` and `1`.

You need to have only `0` th sub array.

**Solution:**

You need to unset `1` st array element.

[unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function is supposed to do that.

```
unset($array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
unset($array_name[1]);
```

In php array is key value pair.

So you are calling '1' key

And you are storing below array on key '1'

```
Array ( [food_name] => Sweet Corn Chicken Soup [food_id] => 6 )
```

So just unset that key

like above I mention

```
unset($array_name[1]);
```

unset() destroys the specified variables.

For more information about unset you can read

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Consider expounding upon your answer; explain *how* and *why* it would work.